# Проблема с возвратом массива JSON ajax запросом. PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Пытаюсь по запросу к скрипту PHP получить результат обработки запроса. Скрипт обработчика срабатывает правильно, но результат обратно в `json` формате получить не получается

```js
/Код js
function addUsesOutSystem() {
            /.../
            $.ajax({
            url: "/api/",
            type: "POST",
            data: data2,
            dataType : "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#response').html("<img src='http://supply-dev.evraz.com/upload/preloader.gif' />");
            },
            success: function(data){
                var returnedData = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(returnedData);

            },
            complete: function(json) {
                $('#response').html(json);

            }
        });
    }
```

```js
<?...
header('Content-type: application/json');
....

foreach ($new_array as $getvalue) {
                        $email = $getvalue;
                        $mx = dns_get_record(end(explode("@", $email)), DNS_MX);
                        $mx = $mx[0]['target'];
                        $socket = fsockopen($mx, 25, $errno, $errstr, 10);
                        if (!$socket) {
                            echo "$errstr ($errno)\n";
                        } else {
                            sWrite($socket, "");
                            sWrite($socket, "EHLO example.com\r\n");
                            sWrite($socket, "MAIL FROM: itsowncordova@gmail.com\r\n");
                            $response = sWrite($socket, "RCPT TO: $email\r\n");
                            sWrite($socket, "QUIT\r\n");
                            fclose($socket);
                            if (substr_count($response, "550") > 0) echo json_encode(array($email => "Не отправлено"));
                            else if (substr_count($response, "250") > 0) if (substr_count($response, "OK") > 0) echo json_encode(array($email => "Отправлено"));
                            else echo json_encode(array($email => "Отправлено"));
                            else echo json_encode(array($email => "Отправлено"));
                        }
                    }
```

Результат php-обработчика такой `array(3) { [0]=> string(27) "sy@mail.com" [2]=> string(23) "itsoa@mail.com" [4]=> string(24) "mail@mail.com" }` Хотелось бы увидеть в ответ формата `json`

Comment: во-первых данный вывод сформирован вызовом `print_r`, которого в приведенном коде нет, а значит выводится где-то в другом месте, а во вторых - `echo json_encode` на каждой итерации цикла не имеет смысла. Соберите все что надо в массив, а потом его после цикла уже выведите .

Comment: и толку от ваших if-ов в конце, если при множестве условий выводите вы всегда одно и то же. отформатируйте код нормально

Comment: @teran спасибо, сейчас переделаю

Comment: `var_dump` там где-то у вас а не `print_r`

Comment: @EvgenyPivovarov,  в обработчиках success() / complete() агрументы их параметров будут иметь тип `array`, а не `string`

Comment: И если `dataType : "json",` то парсить джсон уже __не нужно__.

Comment: @teran вы были правы на счет print_r, но только у меня в коде был уже `echo json_encode(...);`, после того как убрал его - заработало.